Visual Studio 2022 implicit TypeScript references
I'm trying to open a Visual Studio project which works fine in VS2019 in VS2022. The latter doesn't seem to understand types from my other files and third party libraries, similar to this question, e.g:
file1.ts
export class Hedgehog {
    spikes() {
        return 100;
    }
}

file2.ts
var h = new Hedgehog(); // Could not find symbol Hedgehog
// Despite installing nuget packade knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
var five = ko.observable(5); // Could not find symbol ko

All my .ts files have build action "TypeScriptCompile".
I've installed the nuget package for the ts version that's being used:
<package id="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" version="3.6.4" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />

Here are the relevant parts of the .csproj
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.3.6.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.3.6.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" />

...
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
<TypeScriptSkipLibCheck>True</TypeScriptSkipLibCheck>
...
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>None</TypeScriptModuleKind>
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>True</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptOutFile />
<TypeScriptOutDir />
<TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>True</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
<TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptMapRoot />
<TypeScriptSourceRoot />
...
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.3.6.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.3.6.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props'))" />
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.3.6.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.3.6.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets'))" />
</Target>
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.3.6.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.3.6.4\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets')" />

Did I miss anything obvious?

Are you able to share a link to your project?

@morganney I'm afraid not, it's a customer project

For your own files
You need to import the other file (i.e. the module from the other file)
file1.ts
export class Hedgehog {
    spikes() {
        return 100;
    }
}

file2.ts
import {Hedgehog} from "./file1"; // <- mandatory import
var h = new Hedgehog();

For libraries (packages installed using npm)

Make sure you got the library into the project running npm install
If you are using a library which has external type definition, you need to import the typed yourself. For instance lodash has the DT logo  which means you need to run npm i lodash to install the js files and then npm install --save @types/lodash to install the corresponding .dt (definition types) files of lodash.

Other VS Code using tsconfig.json
Also, any editor will try to find a tsconfig.json (or a file which extends this one). There are (at least) 2 important properties which will define the working scope of typescript: files and include.
Example:
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  ...
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

Where:

files : Specifies an explicit list of files to include in the compilation
include: Defines patterns or directories to include in the compilation

Check that your file is properly configured (and that VS is using it)
[Edit]
As you are not using tsconfig.json, here is a possible way to include the files to compile into your project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.9</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
   ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Include specific files -->
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="src/specific-file.ts" />
    
    <!-- Include all .ts files in the src directory and its subdirectories -->
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="src/**/*.ts" />
    
    <!-- Include all .ts files in another_directory but exclude certain files -->
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="another_directory/*.ts" Exclude="another_directory/excluded-file.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Official documentation

To elaborate a bit, I'm not using npm nor a tsconfig.json today. All the configuration is posted in my question.

Ah okay, then check my updated answer using <TypeScriptCompile Include="src/**/*.ts" /> it's hard to test on my side, but if I'm not mistaken, this should specify to tsc where to find the files to compile.
